# WSO2 API Publish erro. Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed WSO2 V 1.10.0 on a EC2 - Windows server 2012. I have customized it to run on the public IP. I have created an API and while trying to publish I am getting the error - "**Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed**" Below is error log.

```
2016-11-28 04:21:54,367 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-32] ERROR APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Authentication failure
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:254)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:89)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:1389)  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(APIProviderImpl.java:1195)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:142)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:668)    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:410)    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:319)...  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3179) at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:149)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:41)
at ..org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Authentication failure
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.stub.APIGatewayAdminStub.getApi(APIGatewayAdminStub.java:3054)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:250)
... 81 more
2016-11-28 04:21:54,836 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-32] ERROR APIExecutor Failed to publish service gateway while executing APIExecutor. 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.FaultGatewaysException
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange(APIProviderImpl.java:1312)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:152)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:668)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:410)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:319)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:469)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1951)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:817)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:796)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3179)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:41)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-28 04:21:54,852 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-32] ERROR DefaultLifeCycle org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish
2016-11-28 04:21:54,883 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-32] ERROR GovernanceArtifactImpl Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:440)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:319)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:469)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1951)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:817)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:796)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3179)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:41)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-28 04:21:54,899 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-32] ERROR UserAwareAPIProvider Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:821)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:796)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3179)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:149)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:41)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:440)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:319)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:469)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1951)
at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:817)
... 67 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an authentication issue when the publisher was trying to talk to the gateway. Make sure you have correct credentials in `<APIGateway>` section in `api-manager.xml`.

Comment: This is how the XML looks like
<!-- Server URL of the API gateway. -->
<ServerURL>https://35.154.40.254:9443/services/</ServerURL>
<!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
<Username>${admin.username}</Username>
<!-- Admin password for the API gateway. -->
<Password>${admin.password}</Password>

<!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway. -->


<GatewayEndpoint>http://35.154.40.254:${http.nio.port},https://35.154.40.254:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>

Comment: I also see in the carbon login screen the server URL is not formed properly. "35.154.40.254://services/" the port number is missing.

Comment: I also see the below error.                                                                                 2016-11-28 07:56:17,538 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-50] ERROR ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the 35.154.40.254:9443//services/LoggedUserInfoAdmin URL.
2016-11-28 07:56:17,544 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-50] ERROR ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the 35.154.40.254:9443//services/AuthenticationAdmin URL.

Comment: 2016-11-28 07:56:17,544 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-50] ERROR AuthenticationAdminClient Error occurred while logging out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the 35.154.40.254:9443//services/AuthenticationAdmin URL.

Comment: Did you change anything in carbon.xml? Can you upload your api-manager.xml to somewhere and provide a link?

Comment: I changed the server URL in Carbon.xml and it is working fine now. api-manager.xml is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jg9U64ck-0SnJ2TFVrdFdYQW8 please check.

Comment: So your issue is resolved? URLs in api-manager.xml look good.

Comment: No, I am still getting the error "Failed to change the life cycle status : Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed"

Comment: in the Carbon login screen the server URL is formed properly.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error `The system cannot infer the transport information from the 35.154.40.254:9443//services/AuthenticationAdmin`? (with double slash after the port)

Comment: Please upload your carbon.xml file too

Comment: Did you change the default admin credentials (i.e. admin:admin)?

Comment: I am not getting "The system cannot infer the transport information" error anymore as I have modified the carbon.xml to reflect the correct server URL. I have not changed the default admin credentials i.e (admin:admin) When I try to publish it fails. The first error in the stack trace is ERROR AxisEngine Authentication failure
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure

Comment: Plz post new error trace. Entire one. Update the question with that.

Comment: Error is same as mentioned in the post heading. Here is the complete trace. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jg9U64ck-0YmJjdUtRZFczc00

Comment: There is a port binding error log in your log file. Try setting `ThriftServerHost` in api-manager.xml to your IP.

Comment: The port binding errors were resolved now. I changed the api-manager.xml and thrift-authentication.xml files.Instead of localhost I had given the private IP of the EC2. I am still getting the error while trying to publish. The trace is placed at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jg9U64ck-0dk5WOHhFUjJQenc/view

Comment: Can you try replacing credentials i `APIGateway` with real values?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this state, I can't say anything else without debugging your system.